# Cannot import pandas in vscode jupyter extensiion

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

As I mentioned, jupyter notebook extension in vscode does not allow me to import pandas for some reason.

When I run `pip install pandas` in terminal,

terminal shows
[image]

However,
in vscode ,
[image],

I am currently using conda environment, what is the problem?

tried changing python environment to conda

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Is possible that you are using 2 different python interpreters or you are just using virtual enviroment. I think quick and dirty solution is to **import** in notebook via [IPython Shell Assignment with !](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html)

`!pip install pandas`
and run cell.[image: !pip install pandas in jupyter]

Comment: I have tried that again but it gives me the same result as

"Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Users/ryaotuix/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (2.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2,>=1.23.2 in /Users/ryaotuix/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pandas) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in /Users/ryaotuix/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /Users/ryaotuix/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pandas) (2022.7)

Comment: I think that your enviroment is broken https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment  I recomend that you reinstall whole enviroment (python, pip, conda)  and install via: conda install pandas https://betterdatascience.com/how-to-install-pandas/